# Can em dash be used to define and give more info about a subject?

Tags: em-dashes

Can I use an em dash to embellish the last word of the original thought?

**Examples:**

I spent my career driving a **Ford F-150**—the most reliable truck ever produced!

The new method is setup for **autonomous learning**—the byproduct of which is self-discipline and independent thought.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do it?  Of course, you just did.
Will your readers understand it?  I believe so.
Is that construction approved by the official grammar board?  There is no such  board.
Must you use an em dash for this?  No, you could use a comma.